# Nullpointer exception at startDisplayPreview()

Tags: android, android-camera

Objective: To draw a re-sizable rectangle on camera preview.

I could not find any definitive answer for the nullpointer exception issue. So I am hoping to solve my problem by posting the question. What I already have:

- correct Android Manifest file(camera permissions and such)
- correct xml file
- one of the answers for a similar question required adding getBestPreviewSize() method, which I tried

  Here is code:

Preview.java

```
public class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public Preview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    // without this constructor, xml which uses this class, will throw this
    // error: class cannot be instantiated
    public Preview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
        Camera.Size size = getBestPreviewSize(params, w, h);

        if (size != null) {
            params.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
        }
        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            return;
        }

        mCamera.startPreview();

        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d("CameraView",
                    "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());

        }

    }

    private Size getBestPreviewSize(Parameters params, int w, int h) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Camera.Size result = null;

        for (Camera.Size size : params.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
            if (size.width <= w && size.height <= h) {
                if (result == null) {
                    result = size;
                } else {
                    int resultDelta = w - result.width + h - result.height;
                    int newDelta = w - size.width + h - size.height;

                    if (newDelta < resultDelta) {
                        result = size;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void onPause() {
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        if (mCamera == null) {
            mCamera = Camera.open();

            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
                mCamera.startPreview();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.d("", "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (mCamera != null) {

            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

}
```

CameraPreview.java with MainActivity()

```
public class CameraPreview extends Activity {

    private Preview mPreview;
    private ImageView mTakePicture, cameraIcon;
    private DrawView dV;
    private boolean mAutoFocus = true;
    private boolean mFlashBoolean = false;
    private Button bDisplayText;
    private RelativeLayout rl;
    private FrameLayout fl;
    Camera c;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mTakePicture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cameraButton);
        bDisplayText = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bDispText);
        fl = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview);
        rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl);
        c = getCameraInstance();

        dV = new DrawView(this);
        dV.invalidate();
        rl.addView(dV);

        mPreview = new Preview(this, c);

        fl.addView(mPreview);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        if (mPreview != null) {
            mPreview.onPause();
            mPreview = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

    }

    private static Camera getCameraInstance() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Camera c = null;
        c = Camera.open();

        return c;
    }

}
```

Edit: LogCat

```
09-06 20:23:15.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2352): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-06 20:23:15.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2352): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-06 20:23:15.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2352):     at com.example.textrecognize.Preview.surfaceCreated(Preview.java:94)
09-06 20:23:15.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2352):     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:543)
09-06 20:23:15.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2352):     at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:81)
09-06 20:23:15.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2352):     at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:169)
09-06 20:23:15.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2352):     at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:671)
09-06 20:23:15.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2352):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1820)
09-06 20:23:15.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2352):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
09-06 20:23:15.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2352):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4214)
09-06 20:23:15.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2352):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
09-06 20:23:15.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2352):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
09-06 20:23:15.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2352):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
09-06 20:23:15.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2352):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
09-06 20:23:15.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2352):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-06 20:23:15.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2352):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-06 20:23:15.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2352):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-06 20:23:15.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2352):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4778)
09-06 20:23:15.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2352):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-06 20:23:15.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2352):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-06 20:23:15.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2352):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-06 20:23:15.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2352):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-06 20:23:15.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2352):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you post the logcat so we know where the NPE is?

Comment: mHolder is null? Did you breakpoint it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

The camera object itself was null. Since my tablet has only one camera, I used Camera.open(0) and voila!

I wish this is mentioned in every camera preview example/tutorial/developer guide.

Thanks guys for the help.

Answer (score 1):

try to use following code to check null exception:

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        if (mCamera == null) {
            mCamera = Camera.open();

            // is mCamera null?
            if (mCamera == null) {
                Log.e("camera", "cannot open camera");
                return;
            }

            // is mHolder null? 
            if (mHolder == null) {
                Log.e("camera", "mHolder == null");
                mHolder = getHolder();
            }

            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
                mCamera.startPreview();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.d("", "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }
```